# htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And I am getting 404 although I can acces it with non-pretty url like this `index.php?link=somepage`

My full url is `http://www.website.com/subfolder/index.php?link=somepage`

I have Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16 and `mod_rewrite` module is loaded.

**Update**

Also when I try with this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Then I can access it with `http://www.website.com/subfolder/?link=somepage`
So this way it works when just removing `index.php`

Is it possible that some additional configuration has to be set on server?

Comment: where is .htaccess file placed? under `subfolder`?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim yes

Comment: so visiting `http://www.website.com/subfolder/somepage` gives you 404?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim yes

Comment: `RewriteBase /subfolder` should do the trick

Comment: @giorgio I tried that already but doesn't help

Comment: is the rewrite module enabled? Try to run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` on your server. If it says `Enabling module rewrite [...]` also run `sudo service apache2 restart`. It's probably a server configuration problem (see @Krishnan's answer), because the rules themselves are ok (check this [rewrite test tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: @giorgio yes it was a server issue but different one, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a server issue including mime types and multiviews.

It's not really issue for stackoverflow but if someone runs into same problems here are sources that solved this problem:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm - remove MultiViews from Virtual Host configuration
- https://serverfault.com/questions/372733/apache-file-negotiation-failed - add missing mime types

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?link=$1
```

Comment: didn't help, I get 404 again

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should check your apache config

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Search for

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**

enable htaccess module by running cmd

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart your server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and use this .htaccess file in your project folder

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Hope it works for u .. :)